# handwriting to text program from multipage scanner

Tags: ocr, invoice, handwriting-recognition

I want to create a program that can scan paper invoices in a multipage scanner and convert them to text in an excel sheet.
My problem:

1. The invoices come from dozens of different food suppliers and have the invoice number, amount, tax etc in different places on the page meaning it would be difficult to decifer when all the text is pulled at once.
2. The program needs to read a few handwritten numbers from a stamp on each invoice as well as printed text.

I don't have any coding experience and am not sure how to go about this / how doable it is.
It sounds relatively easy - the program just dumps all the data from the scanned invoice into a spreadsheet and then organises it, but which programming language is ideal for this?
Is there a program out there already that could be used to process the data?

Sorry if this is an obvious answer / been answered before.
I'd really appreciate any pointers.
Thank you!

Comment: If you don't have any coding experience, I'd suggest starting with a much simpler problem.  This is far more complicated than you're assuming.

Comment: @StephenNewell I doubt I will be doing any of the programming for it, this question is more to get a sense of how hard this will be to develop, and first steps to go about starting this off. I will most likely hire a developer if its reasonably doable but I'd just like some more information. Thank you